# Given a 2D Array (of 0's and 1's), find the minimum number of rows required so that maximum columns have their sum greater than a threshold

Tags: algorithms, logic, sorting, matrices, linear-algebra

I have a 2D array of some rows and columns which are having only 0's and 1's. I would want to know if there is a way to optimize the number of rows so that maximum number of columns have their column sum greater than a threshold (this is known). In the end, I should be able to get the rows which should be considered to achieve this.

Example:

```
   C1 C2 C3 C4
R1  1  1  1  1
R2  0  1  0  1
R3  0  1  1  0
R4  1  0  1  0
(C1, C2, C3, C4 are the columns. R1, R2, R3 and R4 are the rows).
```

If I keep a threshold of 2 for each column, I need to choose only R1, R3 and R4.

Comment: Please credit the source of the original problem such as a url, a textbook or the name of the course/event, etc.

Comment: This is something which I encountered as part of performing a larger task in my research. Hence, I'm not really allowed to share its source.

Comment: I don't understand the problem statement.  You talk about both optimizing the number of rows and maximizing the number of columns.  Those are two different objective functions.  Any algorithm that optimizes one will lead to a non-optimum answer for the other.  Please specify the problem statement more clearly, using mathematics as appropriate.

Comment: Separately: I encourage you to read about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem.

Comment: By "optimize" do you mean "minimize"?